# Cannot connect to OpenVPN server under Ubuntu 14.04 (from terminal), but all is fine in Windows

Tags: command-line, openvpn

In Windows everything is OK.
In Ubuntu when I run

```
sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn
```

I get these error messages:

```
 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
```

What should I to do to fix this?
I already tried to change nobind -> local ip in `client.ovpn` without sucess.

```
2018-01-11 07:03:11+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Thu Jan 11 07:03:11 2018 
188.226.96.50:56532 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]188.226.96.50:56532, sid=b8f1f244 63645f4e'
2018-01-11 07:03:11+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Thu Jan 11 07:03:11 2018 188.226.96.50:56532 OpenSSL: error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol'
2018-01-11 07:03:11+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Thu Jan 11 07:03:11 2018 188.226.96.50:56532 TLS_ERROR: BIO read tls_read_plaintext error'
2018-01-11 07:03:11+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Thu Jan 11 07:03:11 2018 188.226.96.50:56532 TLS Error: TLS object -> incoming plaintext read error'
2018-01-11 07:03:11+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Thu Jan 11 07:03:11 2018 188.226.96.50:56532 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed'
2018-01-11 07:03:11+0000 [-] OVPN 1 OUT: 'Thu Jan 11 07:03:11 2018 188.226.96.50:56532 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting'
```

[client.ovpn](https://jsfiddle.net/8rrz7bLj)

[server settings](https://jsfiddle.net/14njzgrt/) found with `locate .conf | grep openvpn

Comment: Got the right ports open?

Comment: @OrganicMarble How can I check it on the Ubuntu client? I believe, there is no issue on the server, because it's reachable by openvpn's windows clients quite well. sudo nmap -sU -v localhost (or 127.0.0.1) both don't show me 1194 port

Comment: I even tried clean Ubuntu from ISO (try option on bootable USB flash drive). Sudo apt-get install openvpn and then tried to connect. Still has no luck. I don't understand, why it doesn't work on clean install.